# Pass python/django variable into javascript as JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

Woking on personal project website with django 1.9 and python 3.4. I am using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io). The idea is to pass a set of appointment objects into the html page containing the javascript for the calendar. But right now, I am just trying to pass a single default appointment.

In **views.py** I have the following:

```
appt = json.dumps({ "title": "meeting", "start": "2016-11-20"});
return render(request, 'healthnet/profile_patient.html', {'patient': patient, 'appt': appt_set})
```

In **profile_patient.html**:

```
<script>

    var data = jQuery.parseJSON("{{appt}}");

    var events;
    events = [];
    events.push(data);


    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: events
        });
    });
</script>
```

`appt` is not getting properly parsed I believe. When the web page is loaded, the calendar does not display at all.

When I substitute `appt` with the direct string, it does work:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{"title": "meeting", "start": "2016-11-20"}');
```

When I call `alert("{{appt}}");` i get the following:

[image]

So there's something wrong with the way I'm using ths varibale. Any ideas?

Comment: so what happens if you do: console.log(data) ?? does it print null? what does it print out?

Comment: Could you try to change " by '? jQuery.parseJSON('{{appt}}'); ?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the alert message. Alert(data) does nothing. And I cant do a console.log.

Comment: The single quotes didnt change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the safe filter:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('{{appt | safe}}');
```

n.b. you can also do this

```
var apptData = {{ appt | safe }};
```